# Count of chars in NSString or NSMutableString?

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I've tried this

```
NSCharacterSet *myCharSet = [NSCharacterSet characterSetWithCharactersInString: myString];
[myCharSet count];
```

But get a warning that NSCharacterSet may not respond to count.  This is for desktop apps and not iPhone, which I think the above code works with.

Comment: To clarify: you want the number of unique characters in the string?

Comment: No - just the total number of characters.

Answer (score 86, accepted):

I might be missing something here, but what's wrong with simply doing:

```
NSUInteger characterCount = [myString length];
```

To just get the number of characters in a string, I don't see any reason to mess around with NSCharacterSet.

Comment: Just to be clear- `-length` returns `the number of Unicode characters in the receiver.` (as defined by the `NSString` documentation).  Technically, the documentation is wrong because it actually returns `the number of UTF-16 Code Units` and not `the number of Unicode characters`.  This distinction is unimportant for the vast majority of programmers and uses, but it does have important consequences.  For example, `[@"\U0010ffff" length]` returns `2` even though it contains a single Unicode character. `characterAtIndex:` for `0` and `1` returns `0xdbff` and `0xdfff`, respectively.

Comment: ^This is INCREDIBLY important because now a days most iOS users type with emojis which will be considered 2 characters using the `length` method mentioned above... even though it is 1 character.

Comment: this could be more important than you would expect if you happen to be using CoreData, breaking up surrogate pair like "" would fail passing the validation rule of CoreData during commit phase, CoreData gently shows you error code of 1671, which even google doesn't know anything about it, which took me half a year to figure out what's really going on :(

Answer (score 0):

That should not work on the iPhone either, as NSCharacterSet is not a subclass of NSSet on either platform.

If you really need to get a count why not subclass NSSet, add the value, then have a method that returns that as an NSCharacterSet on demand for use in anything that needs a character set?

Comment: NSSet is a class cluster and is therefore not easily (or practically) subclassed.

Comment: Is there not a simple technique for getting a count of all characters within a string?

Comment: Yes there is one (real length) : [myString lengthOfBytesUsingEncoding:NSUTF32StringEncoding] / 4;

Answer (score 0):

```
NSString *string = @"0̄ ";
__block NSUInteger count = 0;
[string enumerateSubstringsInRange:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])
                           options:NSStringEnumerationByComposedCharacterSequences
                        usingBlock:^(NSString *substring, NSRange substringRange, NSRange enclosingRange, BOOL *stop) {
                            count++;
                        }];
NSLog(@"%ld %ld", (long)count, (long)[string length]);
```